# USB Vendor and Product ID to Device Binding

Tags: bash, usb, lsusb

I have a USB VID and PID for an attached device on GNU / Linux. `045e:0084`, for example. I want the binding so I grep the output of `lsusb` for the `VID:PID` and massage it into a format acceptable for `udevadm` lookup. Finally, I take the basename of the resultant path. Something like:

```
bus_dev=$(lsusb|grep VID:PID...) # Grep / Sed magic to extract bus and device from VID and PID.
path=$(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/bus/usb/$bus_dev) # e.g., -n /dev/bus/usb/003/018
basename $path # e.g., /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.3/3-2.3.1
# e.g., yields 3-2.3.1
```

I can then use it like so:

```
echo 3-2.3.1|sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

What's the preferred way to get the binding from a USB vendor and product ID?

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
vidpid="1d6b:0002"
bus_dev=`lsusb | grep "ID\s$vidpid" | sed 's/^.*Bus\s\([0-9]\+\)\sDevice\s\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1\/\2/g' | tail -n 1` 
path=$(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/bus/usb/$bus_dev)
basename $path
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. I don't need the "SED / Grep magic" portion (it's actually what I'm trying to avoid). I've already got that working fine but I was hoping to find something more conventional and less hackish. Perhaps there's a way to query this from udev? Mine's quite similar to yours:

   # $1 - VID[:PID]
   usb_id_to_bind()
   {
      declare -r dev_name="$(lsusb|sed -rn 's_^Bus ([0-9]{3}) Device ([0-9]{3}): ID '"$1"'.*_/dev/bus/usb/\1/\2_p')"
      declare -r dev_path="$(udevadm info -q path -n"$dev_name")"
   
      basename "$dev_path"
   }